# Python updating a dictionary based on most occurred item

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of webpages for example

`pages = [login, ask, profile, search]`

I am busy iterating through a different list of users, each can visit **any** webpage several times.
I need to know who the **top visitor for each page is**. I want to use dictionaries because of its functionality.

This is hard to explain, because I have many many nested structures in my code. To simplify I will both word the problem, and try and illustrate.

PROBLEM:

When iterating through a user, another nested iteration IS a webpage that the user visited.

```
users = ['tom', 'jerry', 'dexter', 'deedee', 'buttercup']

for user in users:
   for session in sessions:
      for page in activities:
            webpage = user_visited  # this can be any of the pages mentioned earlier
```

I need to find a way to see for each `webpage` which `user` visited it **most**

EXPECTING something like this:

```
{ login: dexter, ask: jerry, profile: buttercup, search: tom}
```

I am open to any method, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would maintain a dictionary of webpages and users like this:

```
d = {'login' : {'tom':1, 'jerry':0, 'dexter':2, 'deedee':3, 'buttercup':1},
     'ask' : {'tom':0, 'jerry':0, 'dexter':3, 'deedee':2, 'buttercup':1},
     'profile': {'tom':4, 'jerry':2, 'dexter':2, 'deedee':3, 'buttercup':1},
     'search': {'tom':1, 'jerry':0, 'dexter':2, 'deedee':0, 'buttercup':4},
}
```

where the key is the webpage and the value is a dictionary of users and webpage visits. Increment the count inside the dictionary of each page when a user visits. Then its simple to get the most frequent visitor to each page:

```
from collections import Counter

l = []
for key,dd in d.items():
    c = Counter(dd)
    l.append({key : c.most_common(1)[0]})
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[{'login': ('deedee', 3)}, {'ask': ('dexter', 3)}, {'profile': ('tom', 4)}, {'search': ('buttercup', 4)}]
```

**Update**:

To create your dictionary `d` you firstly need a list of pages and users:

```
pages = ['login', 'ask', 'profile', 'search']
users = ['tom', 'jerry', 'dexter', 'deedee', 'buttercup']
```

You can then create your dictionary using dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {page: {user: 0 for user in users} for page in pages}
```

There are two for loop here - one to iterate the pages and another the users for each page. You will then get a structure like this:

```
{'login': {'tom': 0, 'jerry': 0, 'dexter': 0, 'deedee': 0, 'buttercup': 0},
 'ask': {'tom': 0, 'jerry': 0, 'dexter': 0, 'deedee': 0, 'buttercup': 0},
 'profile': {'tom': 0, 'jerry': 0, 'dexter': 0, 'deedee': 0, 'buttercup': 0},
 'search': {'tom': 0, 'jerry': 0, 'dexter': 0, 'deedee': 0, 'buttercup': 0}}
```

After that it is quite simple to update the web page visit for each user:

```
d['login']['tom'] += 1
```

Comment: Yes, this is the logic I am interested in. How would I go about getting a dictionary ```d``` with my data

Comment: My problem is, that I should create a new key for each 'new' key that appears during iterations, and the value of that key should be one/ or appended by one, all of this while checking if the key already exists

Comment: @LlewellynHattingh See my update for creating the dictionary and updating it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use dictionaries mixed with classes.

```
class Page:
    visited = {}
    mostActiveUser = None
    def visit(self, user):
        if user in self.visited:
            self.visited[user] += 1
        else:
            self.visited[user] = 0
        self.mostActiveUser = max(self.visited, key=self.visited.get) # This will work in Python 3


pages = {'login': Page(), 'ask': Page(), 'profile': Page(), 'search': Page()}
users = ['tom', 'jerry', 'dexter', 'deedee', 'buttercup']

for user in users:
    for session in sessions:
        for page in activities:
            webpage = user_visited
            pages[webpage].visit(user)

# You can access the user who visited the most a page by doing
print(pages['login'].mostActiveUser)

# If you want to see all of the pages most active users
for page in pages:
    print(pages[page].mostActiveUser)
```

Hope this helps,

Tom